# Leaking range hood after heavy storm

Tags: exhaust-fan, rain, hood

Our house is three years old and we just bought it a couple months ago (so I don't know if this is a longstanding issue).  Last night during a heavy rain our kitchen hood range began dripping water onto the stove surface.  The range vents to the side of the house and not the roof.  The vent is covered and a quick look showed the flap was down so its doubtful that it was stuck up and somehow getting water blown in.

The vent itself isn't *completely* flush with the siding but its not far off either.  Purely as a guess I imagine water running down the siding and perhaps leaking in via the top of the vent?  Can I just pick up exterior silicone caulk and flood edges of the range's exaust fan vent to seal it up nice and tight or is there somewhere else I should be looking?

Vent is [similar to this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Master-Flow-4-in-Round-Wall-Vent-WVA4/100396975), but plastic.

[Album of pictures from various angles](https://imgur.com/a/sIiENCE)

Comment: What is directly above this vent hood?  Is it attic, or finished space?  Unless it was really windy to blow rain into your covered vent hood, it's possible the leak is coming from somewhere more above your vent hood.  Without pictures it's hard to tell for sure, but I'd start by investigating what's directly above and see if water is getting in there, and just happens to come out at your vent hood as a place to escape.

Comment: Can you add a pic of your actual vent. Especially from above.  That may help in determining the origin of the leak.

Comment: Yeah, we need to see the situation, both up close and in context.

Comment: I'll upload pictures shortly.  My fault on not doing that in the first place.  As for what's above the kitchen/vent area, its just a second floor spare bedroom.  The house is two stories and an attic.  Directly above the kitchen/stove is just a bedroom.

Comment: Water can leak in from `x` location and run horizontally before dripping out `y` location. The fact that there's a bedroom above does minimize the chances that the water is coming from elsewhere, but doesn't eliminate it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the pics and additional information, I'd just fill the gaps with clear high-quality exterior-grade caulk and hope for the best.  Shame on the installer (either of the vent or the siding) for not sealing that off properly to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is probably a Mid-America hooded wall vent:
https://midamericacomponents.com/product/6-hooded-vent/

It *looks* more or less properly installed from the outside—if a bit crooked.  But who knows?  (I dunno if I'd have gone with white...maybe stock was limited when it was purchased.)  I wonder if it was installed back-pitched, and there's water leaking in and running down the duct.

If you can easily access it (got a long enough ladder), you should be able to remove adjacent siding and see whether or not it was installed correctly.